# NullPointerException in Android application working on GPS

Tags: android, gps, nullpointerexception

I have the following very simple class which looks for the last known user coordinates and then prints one of them. But I am getting loc as null variable. The application is not reading the data into the loc variable.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Navigation extends Activity
    {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        try
        {
            LocationManager mlocManager = 
              (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                  "Provider Enable Status : " + mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(                       
                   mlocManager.getProvider("gps").getName()),     
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Location loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "" + 
                loc.getLatitude(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "" + loc,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         } catch (Exception e) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage() + 
             e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
      }
   }
```

I have added the following listener to the code :

```
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( mlocManager.getProvider("gps").getName(), 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

in the oncreate function. And the following as a class in

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
            "Hi, location changed. :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "My current location is: " +
                " Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +
                " Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And after running the window, I do the following: 
go to DDMS in the Eclipse and set the lattitudes/longtitude and click on the send.

Still it doesn't fire any toast command in the function.

Comment: You are going to run into serious problems with your context handling ... take a look at my answer.

Comment: The code is finally working. (And I will take care of all the good practices that you wrote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do the null check, Thats absolutely fine approach to this issue. Another trick to this is on your onResume() call of activity you request location updates with :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f,this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

In your case **mlocManager**, make sure you create this as an instance variable (class-level) and not local (not defined in method, in your case in onCreate).

This will surely fetch location updates and not throw null pointer. Also make sure you **geofix your GPS configured emulator**. Use DDMS's Emulator Control flyout to do that. fix some longitude and latitiude values before launching you activity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
   mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(mlocManager.getProvider("gps").getName(), 0, 0, mlocListener);  
  

 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
 {
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    String Text = "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), it's explicitly said that the method returns "the last known location for the provider, or null".

I'm no Android developer, but I guess that it returns null on GPS cold boot until a fix has been made. You have to check that loc is `!=null` before continuing. You might try to wait some time or use an async callback.

Hope to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

Which makes sense... because if the device never had a known location, you can't get one.
You should handle the null by yourself. Provide a new Location or wait for the first GPS data...

Answer (score 1):

What WarrenFaith and djechelon said is indeed a good practice. Before using that object you should check for it not being null.

Also consider that if you are inside your activity there is no real need to get the context be calling `getApplication()` and `getBaseContext()`. Substitute them with `this` instead and try again.

You might also want to check your third Toast notification since you are settings its text to be `""+loc` I guess you meant `""+loc.getLongitude()`.

If you need to have you activity's context somewhere in another class then define the context like this.

```
private Context ctx = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    // some code

    ctx = getApplication();

    // some more code

}

// your other class in the same Java file (inner class)

public class MyOtherClass {
    // a construtctor probably
    // some usefull methods
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "My message", 5000).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I will surely incorporate each one of them in the project. Since, I have started not more then 2-3 days ago I am running into this kind or problems.